# Chrony tracking.log showing IP Address of 0.0.0.0

Tags: ntp, chrony

I have a NTP server running chronyd that is configured with the following pool:

```
pool 0.dk.pool.ntp.org iburst
pool 1.dk.pool.ntp.org iburst
pool 2.dk.pool.ntp.org iburst
pool 3.dk.pool.ntp.org iburst
```

Every once in a while, I see an IP Address of 0.0.0.0 in /var/log/chrony/tracking.log.

As you can see in the below output of tracking.log, the polling interval is very stable (every 1024 sec. / 17 minutes) leading up to the IP Address being changed to 0.0.0.0. This correlates with the default MaxPoll, that I have not altered.

Is this simply a case of a peer becoming unresponsive and my NTP server reselecting?

If so, I would assume that my NTP server would first discover the current peer to be unresponsive after 17 minutes, and not after only 5 minutes (19:21 - 19:26) or 10 minutes (02:35 - 02:45).

[image: tracking.log picture 1]

[image: tracking.log picture 2]